# How to solve the following ordinary differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE $$y' + x = \sqrt{x^2+y}.$$
I have no idea how to solve this equation. I have tried several ways but neither of them worked. Can anybody help me? Many thanks.

I have tried substituting $u=\sqrt{x^2+y}$, as well as squaring both sides of the ODE.

Comment: What ways have you tried?

Comment: let u=sqrt(x^2+y) 
u'=(x + y' / 2) / u
then y' = 2(u*u'-x)
put it in the ODE
2u*u'-x=u
but I still can't solve this ODE

Comment: Squaring converts it to $y'^2+2xy' = y$.

Comment: I have tried this way, but then how to solve it?

Comment: Use the [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3374263/edit) link to add details of your solution attempts directly to the question, as that is essential information.

Comment: oh, I see, thanks.

Comment: @ Leucippus I really don't understand why this interesting problem was put on hold. The user has provided information (in a comment) of how far he has come himself and this was a valid step. Then he got stuck an asks for help - a normal procedure in thousands of OPs here. Also consider that two users have put some effort in solving the problem. IMHO the "missing context" could be providided easily by pointing out that "non linear ODEs is a difficult field where few general recipies are available and "good ideas" are requested to solve them. Here's a nut that I couldn't crack."

Comment: From  given equation we get $ y^{.2} + 2xy^{'}-y=0,\quad y'y''+y'+x y^{''}-y'/2=0$ which we get by eliminating sqrt,and differentiating. Eliminate $y'$ you get $f(x,y',y'')=0$ second order ode that is at least neater

Answer (score 3):

Let us assume $g(x)\geq 0$ and  $y=x^2 g(x)^2-x^2$. We have $y'=2x g(x)^2+2x^2 g'(x)g(x)-2x$ and $\sqrt{x^2+y}=x g(x)$,
hence:

$$2 g(x)^2+2x g'(x)g(x)-1 = g(x), $$
$$x g'(x) = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2 g(x)}-g(x). $$
Now let $h(t)=g(e^t)$. We have $h'(t) = e^{t} g'(e^t)$, so $g'(e^t)=h'(t)e^{-t}$ and by letting $x=e^t$ in the previous line
$$ h'(t) = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2 h(t)}-h(t). $$
This is a separable DE, which can be solved by finding the inverse function of $\int \frac{du}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2u}-u}.$
The explicit solutions are a bit convoluted, since they depend on the roots of a cubic. One of them is

$$ y(x) = \frac{x^2}{4}\left[-4+\left(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{2-x^3+2\sqrt{1-x^3}}}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2-x^3+2\sqrt{1-x^3}}}{x}\right)^2\right].$$

Comment: Mathematica gave me a similar solution (in fact 6 solutions which also contained the required constant of integration) but I could not verify explicitly that it was really a solution.  Yours is for $x\lt 1$.

Answer (score 3):

This is a heuristic derivation of the complete solution showing a possible motivation chain. Notice that Jack D'Aurizio has given a special solution before.

How can we simplify the ODE?

$$y' + x = \sqrt{x^2+y}\tag{1}$$

The first thing to do would be to get rid the square root.
Hence the set $v^2 = x^2+y$ so that the r.h.s becomes just $v$.
But this means that $y=v^2-x^2$ and $y'(x) = 2 v v'(x) - 2 x$ so that the the ODE becomes

$$2 v v' - x = v \tag{2}$$

Here we would like to get rid of $x$, hopefully by cancelling a factor $x$. To this end we try the natural substitution $v\to u x$ which gives

$$ 2 u x (u x)' -x = u x \implies 2 u (u x)' -1 = u \implies 2 u^2 +2 x u u' = u+1 \\\implies  x  u' = -u +\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2u} $$

Now we can separate variables:

$$ x  \frac{du}{dx} = -u +\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2u} \implies \frac{du}{-u +\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2u}} =\frac{dx}{x} $$

Integrating is elementary on both sides. Hence we find the following relation betwee $x$ and $u$

$$2 \left(-\frac{1}{3} \log (1-u)-\frac{1}{6} \log (2 u+1)\right)=\log (x) + const\tag{3}$$

Multiplying by $-3$ and simplifying the $\log$ gives the cubic equation for $u$

$$(1-u)^2(1+2u) = \frac{c^3}{x^3} \tag{4}$$

Here $c$ is a constant of integration.

Now $(4)$ can be solved by standard methods giving three solution for $u(x)$. We skip the explicit expression here for the time being as Jack has already given a special solution.

Finally, we have found that the ODE $(1)$ has three solutions given by

$$y(x) = x^2(u(x)^2-1)$$

explicitly

$$y(x,c) = \left\{x^2 \left(\frac{1}{4} \left(-\frac{g}{c x}-\frac{c x}{g}+1\right)^2-1\right),\\x^2 \left(\frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{g}{c x}+\frac{c x}{g}+1\right)^2-1\right),\\x^2 \left(-1+\frac{1}{16} \left(\frac{2 (-1)^{2/3} g}{c x}+\frac{c \left(x-i \sqrt{3} x\right)}{g}+2\right)^2\right)\right\}
\tag{5a}$$

here

$$g = \sqrt[3]{c^3 x^3+2 \sqrt{1-c^3 x^3}-2}\tag{5b}$$

Here is a plot of the three solutions with  three different parameters $c$

[image]

Notice the interesting cusp structure from which two of the three solutions emerge. The position of the cusp is given by $(x,y) = (\frac{1}{c} ,-\frac{1}{c^2})$

**Discussion**

1. CAS

Mathematica solves the ODE with the command DSolve immediately, but it returns 6 solutions instead of 3. Three of these do not solve the ODE after explicit insertion. This confused my at first so I did not submit that solution. The reason is that Mathematica takes a an additional negative value of the square root into account, i.e. it simultaneously solves the ODE $y'+x = - \sqrt{x^2+y}$. The latter is obtained from $(1)$ by the substitution $x\to -x$.

2. Modifications

We could simplify the ODE $(1)$ by subsequently modifying terms, as for instance

$$y'(x)=\sqrt{y(x)}\tag{m1}$$
$$y'(x)=\sqrt{y(x)+x}\tag{m2}$$
$$y'(x)=\sqrt{y(x)+x^2}\tag{m3}$$
$$y'(x)+x=\sqrt{y(x)}\tag{m4}$$
$$y'(x)+x=\sqrt{y(x)+x}\tag{m5}$$

All these ODEs can be transformed to a separable ODE which even can be integrated but the resulting implicit equations cannot be solved explicitly.

For example, the integral of $(m4)$ is

$$\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{2 y(x)}{x^2}+\sqrt{\frac{y(x)}{x^2}}+1\right)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}\text{arctan}\left(\frac{1+4 \sqrt{\frac{y(x)}{x^2}}}{\sqrt{7}}\right)=\log \left(\frac{c}{x}\right)\tag{i4}$$

Comment: That’s awesome! Just the method I want. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ wilam lu Glad you like it. It was fun for me too, and maybe my intervention has prevented the problem from being removed. But I would also appreciate if you would include some background information as e.g. origin of the problem, why did you chose it (as you can see in my solution there are many similar problems of the same type.)